# Linq Out of memory exception

Tags: vb.net, linq

when i execute this code

```
Dim lstOrders = (From oRR In dbO.orders
                 Where oRR.datum = werkdatum And oRR.status >= 40).ToList

Dim lstOrderRegels = (From ord In lstOrders
                     Join ordreg In dbO.orderregels On ord.ID Equals ordreg.ordernummer
                     Group Join a In dbO.artikelen On ordreg.artikelID Equals a.ID Into resultArt = Group
                     From art In resultArt.DefaultIfEmpty(New artikelen With {.ID = 0, .subgroep = 0})
                     Group Join subgr In dbO.productsubgroep On art.subgroep Equals subgr.ID Into result = Group
                     From sgr In result.DefaultIfEmpty(New productsubgroep With {.ID = 0, .productgroep_ID = 0})
                     Group Join hgr In dbO.productgroep On sgr.productgroep_ID Equals hgr.ID Into result2 = Group
                     From hg In result2.DefaultIfEmpty(New productgroep With {.ID = 0})
                     Join ses In dbO.sessie On ord.sessieID Equals ses.ID
                     Order By hg.code, sgr.code).ToList
```

i get a system out of memory execption.. First i though it could be the null value in one of the columns but even changing it to 0 it did not help. That second query should return around 4k result.

Comment: Where do you get the exception? What's the size of `lstOrders`?

Comment: @JonSkeet I get the exception in dim lstOrderregels. The size of lstOrders is 85 rows, the expected size of lstOrderregels is around 4k

Comment: try `Take 10` before calling `ToList` function, to find whether the exception has to do with the size of data returned

Comment: @AhmadIbrahim sory for the late reply, i tried the take 10 and i still get the same problem.